# How to show $|x|$ is convex on R?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How to show $f(x):=|x|$ is convex on R?

$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}x & x\geq 0 \\ -x & x<0 \end{array} \right.$

$f'(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 &x> 0 \\ -1 & x<0 \end{array} \right.$ $\; \; f'(x)$ does not exist for $x=0$

$f''(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 &x> 0 \\ 0 & x<0 \end{array}\right.$

But still I don't know $f''(0)$

I wanted to show $f''(x)\geq 0 \; \forall \; x \in R$ to show that it is convex on R

Comment: Have you tried checking the definition of convexity directly?

Comment: Yes I know this definition but I haven't tried solving it by definition

Comment: It's often helpful to draw a picture when asking whether or not a function is convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using the definition? You have

$$\left|tx_{1}+\left(1-t\right)x_{2}\right|\leq t\left|x_{1}\right|+\left(1-t\right)\left|x_{2}\right|$$

for every $x_{1},x_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in\left[0,1\right]$ by the triangle inequality.

Note that $f^{\prime\prime}\left(0\right)$ doesn't exist because $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: I have generally solved convexity questions by the second derivative test so  it slipped my mind. Thank you :)